# Как получить путь к дата директории приложения?

Tags: android

Как получить путь к директории в которой я мог бы сохранить изображение во внутренней памяти андроид, при этом нужно чтобы изображение не было видно у пользователя в галерее?

Comment: Нужно добавить файл .nomedia и всё

Comment: а как получить путь к директории для сохранения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

при сохранении указывай только имя файла, без пути. Он сам ляжет в data